# Which characters' dead/alive status is different between the ends of Game of Thrones season 5 and A Dance With Dragons?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

No particular reason for asking, and **please don't post any comments** about spoiler-y things GRRM or anyone else may or may not have mentioned in interviews about upcoming twists in upcoming books or seasons of the TV show. Purely in-universe, please.

And **nothing from Winds of Winter preview chapters, too**, please. *Especially* if they confirm someone I think is dead is actually alive, or vice versa... Answers purely based on in-universe knowledge from the books up to ADWD and the show up to season 5.

---

Off the top of my head, I can think of a few, for example:

> Barristan Selmy is dead in the show but alive in the books

...and I know there are a few more, but I can't think who they are.

If someone's implied-dead in one and explicitly dead or alive in the other, that's worth mentioning with a caveat, for example:

> Myrcella Lannister is shown to be dying in the show but is alive in books, but the show doesn't rule out the possibility of a last-moment antidote

...but let's leave out character non-appearances (including odd cases like Lady Stoneheart).

Let's also leave out people who are implied as being dead in both but whose deaths are equally unconfirmed in both, like:

> Stannis and Jon Snow

Likewise let's leave out characters who are dead in both but died differently, like the Tickler.

Obviously, only characters who exist as named characters in both show and books.

---

<sub>On-topic note: questions asking for *finite* lists of things are on-topic and there are hundreds of examples on this site with great answers. It's *never-ending* lists with an unlimited number of possible examples that are off-topic here.</sub>

Comment: Pictures released from the show on its facebook page last month indicate that Myrcella is indeed dead on the show. On the phone now so cannot add a link, may circle back later if no one beats me to it.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister OP did ask for no spoilers of that sort, but since they've now dissociated their account from this question (to avoid spoilers), I guess it doesn't matter any more.

Comment: @randal'thor would argue not a spoiler as a) survival of Myrcella was basically impossible. She was at sea and it was made clear that the antidote needed to be administered almost immediately to save her. And there would be no reason for there to be any of the antidote on the boat. And b) the show clearly felt it was clear Myrcella would die (otherwise they would not have "spoiled" it).

Comment: But I do apologise if anyone felt that was a spoiler.

Answer (score 7):

From the Wall,

> Pyp and Grenn

[were](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Pypar) both [killed](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Grenn) in season 4 of *Game of Thrones*, but are [both](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Pypar) still [alive](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Grenn) as of the end of the fifth book *A Dance With Dragons*.

---

In the Baratheon family,

> Selyse and Shireen (Stannis's wife and daughter)

[are](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Shireen_Baratheon) both [dead](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Selyse_Florent) by the end of season 5 of *Game of Thrones*, but are [both](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Shireen_Baratheon) still [alive](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Selyse_Florent) as of the end of the fifth book *A Dance With Dragons*. In addition,

> Stannis Baratheon

is apparently [killed](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Stannis_Baratheon) at the end of season 5 of *Game of Thrones*, although in *A Dance With Dragons* [his](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stannis_Baratheon) death is only *claimed* to be true by the notorious liar Ramsay Snow/Bolton.

Comment: It's pretty obvious what's in the spoiler from how you've worded the other text. OP might not be happy about that.

Comment: @OrangeDog Sorry, I thought I'd made it ambiguous enough. Better now?

Comment: @OrangeDog OK, since that last bit doesn't really add much to the answer, I've removed it. No spoilers any more! :-)

Comment: No, it's still a spoiler, by virtue of that character being mentioned in an answer to this question at all.

Answer (score 6):

At least one other:

> Balon Greyjoy.

He was "thrown" from a bridge. That starts the Kingsmoot story line for the

> Greyjoy family. Namely Euron, Victarion, and Asha (aka Yara in the show).

From the show previews, it seems like this next season will introduce this as,

> Victarion plans to meet and marry Daenerys.

---

Also,

> Stannis

is not "implied dead" in "both" and has not yet reached

> Winterfell

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers I can think of

> Irri, who is still alive in the books. And Rakharo, one of Dany's bloodriders who is also still alive in the books

And also

> Meryn Trant who is alive in the books but killed by Arya in the series

And

> Jojen Reed is also still alive in the books

And of course

> Grand Maester Pycelle and Kevan Lannister who are killed in the books by Varys

And

> Mance Rayder probably also is still alive in the books

And this minor character

> Joyeuse Erenford, wife of Walder Frey, killed at the Red Wedding on the show is probably still alive in the books

And these minor characters

> Mago, Pyat Pree, Xaro Xhoan Daxos and Martyn Lannister are all still alive in the books